# Inconsistent glue for name server

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone, dns-hosting

I'm getting the error "Inconsistent glue for name server" for our domain webhost.pro on the third name server.

Not sure why, the third name server resolves correctly and has the correct DNS details.

Any idea how to narrow down what the error is with our third name server?

> Delegation
>
> Inconsistent glue for name server ns3.webhost.pro.
>
> The address of a name server differed from the child and the parent.
>   This is a configuration error and should be corrected as soon as
>   possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current DNS configuration has many errors, see this online troubleshooting tool: http://dnsviz.net/d/webhost.pro/WwT6yw/dnssec/

It shows 9 errors, probably all tied to the problem below as they come from the `168.144.134.160` IP address.

And one warning which is what you report:

> pro to webhost.pro: The glue address(es) for ns3.webhost.pro (168.144.134.160) differed from its authoritative address(es) (104.225.130.130).

Here is why.

You are using `ns1.webhost.pro`, `ns2.webhost.pro` and `ns3.webhost.pro` as authoritative nameservers for `webhost.pro`. Hence you need glues.

Here is what the registry thinks about your IP addresses:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 ; do dig @a0.pro.afilias-nst.info. ns$i.webhost.pro A | grep ^ns$i.webhost.pro | awk '{print $1 " " $5}' ; done
ns1.webhost.pro. 104.223.9.2
ns2.webhost.pro. 104.223.9.254
ns3.webhost.pro. 168.144.134.160
```

Now let us query each authoritative nameserver of your zone for the same question, we get respectively from `ns1`, `ns2`, `ns3` the following:

```
$ for auth in 1 2 3 ; do echo "Querying ns${auth}" ; for i in 1 2 3 ; do dig @ns${auth}.webhost.pro ns$i.webhost.pro A | grep ^ns$i.webhost.pro | awk '{print $1 " " $5}' ; done ; done
Querying ns1
ns1.webhost.pro. 104.223.9.2
ns2.webhost.pro. 104.223.9.254
ns3.webhost.pro. 104.225.130.130
Querying ns2
ns1.webhost.pro. 104.223.9.2
ns2.webhost.pro. 104.223.9.254
ns3.webhost.pro. 104.225.130.130
Querying ns3
ns1.webhost.pro. 104.223.9.2
ns2.webhost.pro. 104.223.9.254
ns3.webhost.pro. 104.225.130.130
```

(and if we query `168.144.134.160` as reported by the registry for `ns3` we get no replies)

All three responds the same thing, which is good, but they do not reply exactly what the registry nameservers reply, hence the warning about this mismatch.

The registry has IP `168.144.134.160` for `ns3.webhost.pro` but your nameserver are stating that its IP is `104.225.130.130`

You now have 2 possible choices to resolve it:

1. Make the change at the registry, so that it will also reply  with IP `104.225.130.130` ; you will need to contact your domain name registrar, *OnlineNIC, Inc.* to have the glue record of `ns3.webhost.pro` be updated at the registry with the correct IP.
2. **OR** if `168.144.134.160` is also yours (which does not seem the case based on a comparison of the whois output for both blocks of IP addresses), you need to move `ns3` on it and change the content of your zone to use this IP address.

The first option is probably the simplest one. And the only one if `168.144.134.160` is indeed not yours.

Also, for various reasons, I recommend you **NOT** to use only in-bailiwick nameservers for your domain. You should at least add a `ns4` that does not live under `webhost.pro` as authoritative for your `webhost.pro` domain name. Ideally, use even an another TLD.

Comment: Your option 2 seems solely theoretical as everything else is coherent. The glue record for `ns3` should be modified to match. The fact that `104.225.130.130` responds authoritatively whereas `168.144.134.160` doesn't is the clearest evidence.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I can agree it is the most **probable** case, but better to be exhaustive and the fact that the other IP does not respond could be just another error, in some network firewall or whatever. So there are two cases, one being far more probable than the other but we can not decide instead of the OP.

Comment: `the third name server resolves correctly and has the correct DNS details` pretty much rules this out.

Comment: No, there could be 4 of them (or a migration from one IP to another so the old one may not have been decomissioned yet why the new one may not work already) and an error in setup.

Comment: Thanks, the register OnlineNIC must not be using the wrong IP for our third one! I'll contact them to have it fixed right away. Thank you.